# JavaScript Communication

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I was reading about Flex- JavaScript communication via ExternalInterface.

But I had a doubt, it said that the javascript code should be written in the HTML file of the application ?

Now which is this HTML file ? 
Is it the `index.template.html` file per project or the `HTML file created per MXML application` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use the `index.template.html`, since this is the file used as a template for the HTMLs generated for each MXML application. Otherwise a simple clean on the project might delete the code you've added to the HTML file created per MXML application.

Comment: But when I added that javascript code in the index.template.html file, and I recompiled my application, the code got erased. Any soln ?

Comment: The code gets erased only if you change the required version of Flash and the IDE rebuilds the html-wrapper. In the process it deletes the custom code within the index.template.html. But once generated it shouldn't get erased. At least with my projects I can't recall experiencing your issue. You may check the project properties dialog and uncheck the **Generate HTML wrapper** option within the **Flex Compiler**-tab

Comment: I need your help. When I edited the index.template.html file, Flash Builder started showing me 3 `missing ;` errors near `*Major, minor version of flash player*` in the file. What should be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or if it's a lot of javascript, you could externalize it by including a script tag in the index.template.html file. The index.template.html file is used to generate the index.html files in bin-debug and bin-release folders.

Comment: But when I added that javascript code in the index.template.html file, and I recompiled my application, the code got erased. Any soln ?

Answer (score 0):

this pages describe external interface very well. Most important thing to not forget is

```
 <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
```

And for better flash embeding, use http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ .

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6